# Webtrc broadcast have multiple bandwidth usage

Tags: socket.io, webrtc, multipoint

I want to create a webrtc broadcasting demo

https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/socket.io/

here i have a one problem broadcaster have huge bandwidth when connect 10+ user because it use peer to peer connection so it use upload bandwidth like this

Total upload bandwith = number of user * ( 30 kb approximate to upload 1 video)

so i want to develop like this

http://bloggeek.me/webrtc-multipoint-small-groups

how to i develop multipoint webrtc using minimum bandwidth ?

Comment: Try peer-to-server to --> all other peers model: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.dev.media/pos7woJMimo

Comment: Any other thing for the decrease the uploading bandwidth usage in the webrtc

Comment: proxy with websocket it is possible ?

Comment: Here is my idea (just my idea!): https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/17#issuecomment-16919127

Answer (score 1):

While your thought of using WebRTC in a small group multipoint manner, this comes with a lot of complexity and reliability issues. Most WebRTC apps that relay through peers tend to be not so reliable in my experience.  In concept it's a great idea, but I haven't seen any solid practical applications.  The most reliable implementations of scalable WebRTC broadcasts tends to use a server in the middle.  You can use something like Janus, but I prefer Kurento which is open source.  There is also a platform called OpenVidu that sits on top of Kurento if you don't want to have to get into the nuts and bolts of how things works, but is less customize-able.  You can even record, transcode and process the video in real time.